# How to count total points of a user using Gioco gem's methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to know that how can we find  the total points earned by a user. I am using [gioco gem](https://github.com/joaomdmoura/gioco) in my Ruby on Rails application.

I can add badges and points but when I add points to user's table it makes new entry to it. but how can we count the total points. I want to find the sum of points achieved by the user.

I have already studied github for it but no methods are provided for summing up the points.

I have also tried [merit](https://github.com/tute/merit) gem but it didn't work in my app. I don't know the reason behind it.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show some code and people will be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the [gioco gem](https://github.com/joaomdmoura/gioco), the following is the way to count the total number of points of a user as seen in the specs at https://github.com/joaomdmoura/gioco/blob/master/spec/specs/resources_spec.rb

Assumes you have defined `user` as an instance of `User` model

```
user.points.where(:kind_id => kind.id).sum(:value)
```

Comment: @Nishant great. Please up vote and accept as the solution so others with the same question benefit too.